# How to backup Amazon RDS database to S3 bucket using Lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

How can I backup an Amazon RDS database to S3 bucket using an AWS Lambda function?

Is there is a Lambda script available?

The information in RDS should be backed-up to the S3 bucket and  scheduled every hour using the Lambda function.

Comment: What RDS are you using? MySQL, PostGres, Aurora?

Comment: i am using rds with sql server

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RDS has a **Snapshot** feature that is backs-up the data contained in the database. A Snapshot can be restored to a new Amazon RDS instance.

If you wish to trigger the Snapshot every hour, you could:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that calls the RDS `CreateSnapshot()` API call
- Configure an **Amazon CloudWatch Events schedule** to trigger the Lambda function at desired intervals

Alternatively, you could use [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/how-it-works.html) with a cron expression to trigger an Amazon RDS backup.

Answer (score 1):

You could give https://github.com/intuit/Trapheus a try. This is a complete solution built using AWS Step functions and Lambdas. Could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a Lambda function, but perhaps look into the Database Migration Service. This allows you to migrate data from RDS to S3. It's not specifically cheap, but it is high performance and once setup can be configured to take snapshots at any interval you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add here, AWS gives features directly to exports RDS snapshot to S3. It is launched in US-EAST-1 Region. [image]

Thanks,

Ashish

Comment: And you can call this from lambda using the start_export_task function & call it from a chron scheduled cloudwatch event. You can also add a step to cleanup expired backups.

Comment: Is this approach viable if the Database size is in GBs and have to regularly move the data, let's say everyday?